# Not able to verify the downloaded file with Chrome WebDriver running headless

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, c#, selenium-webdriver-c#, headless

We are trying to verify the downloaded file in headless mode with C#, the file is downloading but not saving in the download path, so my test script is failing.

Any idea for this?

The code is below

```
ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions(); 
option.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", @"%USERPROFILE%\Downloads"); 
option.AddArgument("--headless"); 
option.AddArgument("--window-size=1920,1080"); 
option.AddArguments("--disable-web-security"); 
option.AddArguments("--allow-running-insecure-content"); 
driver = new ChromeDriver(option);
```

Comment: Hi put the script you used to download and verify the file

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem recently I had to add extra options to set the download path for headless.

```
    var options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.AddArgument("--headless");
    options.AddArgument("--disable-extensions");
    options.AddArgument("--disable-gpu");
    options.AddArgument("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
    options.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");
    options.AddArgument("--ignore-certificate-errors");
    options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", Path.GetTempPath());
    options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.directory_upgrade", true);
    options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.prompt_for_download", false);

    var driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

    var settingForHeadlessDownloads = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "behavior", "allow" },
        { "downloadPath", Path.GetTempPath() }
    };
    driver.ExecuteChromeCommand("Page.setDownloadBehavior", settingForHeadlessDownloads);
```

This answers has some more details, apperently it is a security feature, but is for Python. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45631715/downloading-with-chrome-headless-and-selenium

Comment: we tried this already ,still no luck with chrome version 78.

Comment: ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
                    option.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", @"%USERPROFILE%\Downloads");
option.AddArgument("--headless");
                    option.AddArgument("--window-size=1920,1080");
                    option.AddArguments("--disable-web-security");
                    option.AddArguments("--allow-running-insecure-content");
driver = new ChromeDriver(option);

Comment: What is that last comment?

Comment: we tried above code along with the shared script,but not sure where we are failing

Comment: Added my full options code aswell. I am on chrome v77 and cannot upgrade soon to test if it still works.